disable li items in navigation bar HTML
I have a simple navigation bar, this is the HTML
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="menubar">
      <ul class="menulist">
        <li id="login" class="login"><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
        <li id="settings" class="settings"><a href="settings.html">Settings</a></li>
        <li id="conf" class="conf"><a href="conf.html">Configuration</a></li>
        <li id="about" class="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>
</body>

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
  }

  ul li a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14;
    font-style: arial;
    color: #1e1e1e;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }


I would like to disable the menu items, except for the login, until the user actually login in the page.
I saw a lot of example online but nothing really working.
Could you please give me an example? I'm new to HTML and trying to learn.
Thanks in advence for your time
I've tried to use classes, as you can see, but not clear how to use them in JS

It looks like the things you ask for, are way more complicated than you describe here. How do you decide if a user is logged in? What is the use case? Your problem you pose is just to put a class dynamically based on a condition, but this may turn out more difficult than excepted if the condition is a user session. Anyhow here is a link to add, remove classes with JS: https://medium.com/@shivani.007/classlist-in-javascript-b73cfc598e70#:~:text=The%20add()%20method%20of,or%20behavior%20on%20the%20webpage

I was thinking to add a login/logout button and fields in the first page.
Once logged in I would enable the other menus and disable them again when the user logout. I come from VB programming, where everithing on the form is basically in one place. Trying HTML now and I don't understand how to link all the modules together. Maybe the question would be more easy if I put it like this:
Given the navigation bar, how do I manage the click event on a button to enable/disable the oher menus ?

You'd manage the click event with an event listener addEventListener. But, FWIW, there are no buttons in the code you have provided.

I would suggest you go with a semantic approach for class names, in this case I would use disabled. When the user is not logged in then add the disabled class to each li that requires this class, you can then use pointer-events none on the disabled class https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events which stops the user from being able to click the elements in question. Remove the disabled class once the user is logged in to allow them to navigate again.

After login, add the 'logged' class to the <ul> element


ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14;
  font-style: arial;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
ul li.login {
  display: block;
}

/* After login */
ul.logged li.login {
  display: none;
}
ul.logged li:not(.login) {
  display: inline-block;
}
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="menubar">
      <ul class="menulist"> <!-- After login, add the 'logged' class to the <ul> element -->

        <li id="login" class="login"><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
        <li id="settings" class="settings"><a href="settings.html">Settings</a></li>
        <li id="conf" class="conf"><a href="conf.html">Configuration</a></li>
        <li id="about" class="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>
</body>




You can do this by a simple JQuery script. Here I moved your id and class from 'li' to 'a'


$(document).ready(function() { 
      $('.menulist a').click(function(e){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('login'))
        e.preventDefault();
      });
});
 ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
  }

  ul li a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14;
    font-style: arial;
    color: #1e1e1e;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <header>
    <nav class="menubar">
      <ul class="menulist">
        <li><a id="login" class="login" href="login.html">Login</a></li>
        <li><a id="settings" class="settings" href="settings.html">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a id="conf" class="conf" href="conf.html">Configuration</a></li>
        <li><a id="about" class="about" href="about.html">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>



If you still want to use id and class on 'li' itself please check below


$(document).ready(function() { 
      $('.menulist a').click(function(e){
        if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('login'))
        e.preventDefault();
      });
});
 ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
  }

  ul li a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14;
    font-style: arial;
    color: #1e1e1e;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <nav class="menubar">
      <ul class="menulist">
        <li id="login" class="login"><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
        <li id="settings" class="settings"><a href="settings.html">Settings</a></li>
        <li id="conf" class="conf"><a href="conf.html">Configuration</a></li>
        <li id="about" class="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>




You can wrap your optional items into another element with style display: none, and after login, add hide class to the login element and remove it from the class attribute of options.


const loginElement = document.getElementById("login");
const optionsElement = document.getElementById("options");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

//after login
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  loginElement.classList.add("hide");
  optionsElement.classList.remove("hide");
});
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14;
  font-style: arial;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="menubar">
        <ul class="menulist">
          <li id="login"><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
          <div id="options" class="hide">
            <li id="settings" class="settings">
              <a href="settings.html">Settings</a>
            </li>
            <li id="conf" class="conf">
              <a href="conf.html">Configuration</a>
            </li>
            <li id="about" class="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <button id="btn">Click</button>

  </body>
</html>




I don't know what language you use to make the login, but hope this help! I've also add some explanation in the code


ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: none; /*add this to hide all the menu*/
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14;
  font-style: arial;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

/*add these*/
ul li.login {
  display: block;
}

/*add these to make an exception*/
ul.logged li {
  display: inline-block;
}
/*you need to add class 'logged' to 'ul' element after the user logged in, then all the menu will showing*/
<nav class="menubar">
  <ul class="menulist">
    <li id="login" class="login"><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
    <li id="settings" class="settings"><a href="settings.html">Settings</a></li>
    <li id="conf" class="conf"><a href="conf.html">Configuration</a></li>
    <li id="about" class="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>



